# Electric field due to a short dipole at a point $A$ on the axis

Tags: electric-fields, dipole, dipole-moment

1. There is a short dipole $ X,Y$ of charge $+q$ and $-q$ placed along the x-axis and then we consider the point at $A$ which is far away from the dipole and lies on the x-axis. The electric field $E_\text{net}$ experienced at that point will be $E_\text{net}=E_\text{XA}+E_\text{YA}$ where the $E_{ij}$ are vectors. The dipole charges also interact with each other. Why are we **only** considering the interaction between the dipole and the unit postive test charge at the point $A$?
2. Would it be the same if we did the following? Keep a positive charge $+q$ at the origin and another positive charge at a distance far away on the x-axis. After that, introduce a negative charge $-q$ near to the origin. Will this result in the same configuration (in terms of electric fields) as in the previous case?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to know the electric field strength at point A due to the point charges at X and Y, you do not need to know the strength of the electric force between the charges X and Y because this interaction does not affect the strength of the interaction which each of X and Y have at A. The charge at X exerts the same force on A regardless of where Y is placed. It is not weakened by interacting with the charge at Y.

Electric field is not like the flow of water from a tap. Assuming the tap cannot be opened further to increase the flow (litres per second), if more water flows from X to Y then there is less available to flow from X to A. If you remove the connection to Y then all of the water can flow to A, making this flow "stronger" (more litres per second).

2. Yes the force on A would be exactly the same if the charges at X, Y and A are put into position in the order X, A then Y or A, Y then X, etc. The electric field does not have a memory of what happened previously. It only depends on the final configuration.

Both observations are summarised by the **Principle of Superposition** which applies in all linear systems. This says that the effect of a combination of 2 things X and Y is the sum of the effect of each of X and Y acting separately, as though the other were not there at all. Their effect on other objects is not changed at all by their effect on each other.